# Proving uniqueness of Hausdorff moment problem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, moment-problem

I want to prove that a positive measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with *compact support* is *uniquely determined* by its moments
$$
m_k = \int_{\mathbb{R}}x^k d\mu(x).
$$

I have looked through a lot of literature, but I only come across sources that say it's automatic or obvious.

The only tip I could find was from wikipedia's Moment Problem article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem

> The uniqueness of μ in the Hausdorff moment problem follows from the Weierstrass approximation theorem, which states that polynomials are dense under the uniform norm in the space of continuous functions on [0, 1].

But I don't know what to do with this information. We don't know that $\mu$ is continuous right?

**So far this is what I have.**
If we have two compactly supported measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ with the same moment sequence $(m_n)_{n\geq 0}$, than they will have the same Laplace transform.

$$
\mathcal{L}[\mu](z) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-zx}d\mu(x) = \int_{-T}^T e^{-zx}d\mu(x) 
= \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{(-z)^n}{n!}m_n = \mathcal{L}[\nu](z).
$$

In addition we can show that $\exists C>0:\,$ $|m_n|\leq C^n$ because of the compact support. From this it follows that the Laplace transform is entire. If we can now invert the Laplace transform we would be done. But I'm not sure how this works, because the ordinary *inverse Laplace transform* that we can find e.g. here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform gives you a function whereas I would like a map from Borel subsets to $\mathbb{R}$.

**In Summary:**
Can anyone help me prove uniqueness for the Hausdorff moment problem? Either along the way I was trying or any other.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, [Hausdorff moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_moment_problem).

Comment: If two measures with compact support satisfy this, then $\int p d\mu =\int p d \nu$ for all polynomials. By the Weierstrass approximation theorem, this implies $\int f d\mu =\int f d\nu$ for all continuous functions with compact support, and hence for all continuous functions (since both measures have compact support). It is well known that this implies that the measures coincide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple proof is based on [Markov-Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem), which state that the dual of the space of continuous functions over a compact set is the set of radon measures of finite variation on the same compact :
$$
(\mathcal{C}^0(K))^*=\mathcal{M}(K)
$$
We consider the Riesz Functional :
$$
\matrix{
\varphi : &\mathbb C[X]&\to & \mathbb C\\
 & \sum_{k\le p} a_k x^k  & \mapsto & \sum_{k\le p} a_k m_k}
$$
Since the support is compact, we get that
$$
|\varphi(p)|=\left|\int_K p(t)d\mu(t) \right|\le \|p\|_{\infty}\mu(K)
$$
We can extend uniquely now (Thanks to the last inequality) the functional $\varphi$ to $\overline{\mathbb C[X]|_K}^\infty$, but by Stone-Weierstrass theorem $\overline{\mathbb C[X]}^\infty=\mathcal C^0(K)$.

So from the moment sequence $(m_k)_k$ we can construct a unique continuous linear functional $\varphi\in (\mathcal{C}^0(K))^*$, then by the uniqueness of the representing measure on Markov-Risez theorem, this measure will be unique solution of the moment problem.